# Select text after other tags inside div

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a structure like this :

```
<div class="cls">
  <a>
     <s>#</s>
     some text
</a>
</div>
```

How can i select that 'some text' for processing in another function ? 
I was thinking of

```
$(".cls").innerHTML;
```

but i guess i would have to parse it, do i have any other easier solution ?

Would this be a better solution ?

```
var word = $(".cls").next('a').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).filter('s').remove();
```

i have mistaken the html i am truly sorry

Later edit: 
What if there are multiple  tags (identical) and i want to get the "some text" from every one of them? Do i need to count them and use a for structure to work with every one of them ?

Comment: `s`? is this a new element?

Comment: @undefined its a pretty old element, s for strikethrough

Comment: That is how the page looks and i cannot change that in any way though check my possible answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution it is like this :

```
var text=$('.cls').children().text();
```

as simple as that. It looks like i was complicating the thing more than it needed.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you `some text`:

```
var text = $('.cls').contents().filter(function() {
               return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
           }).text();
```

Comment: i have reviewed the html please reform the answer